# How to get the value for the two dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

I want to select the value between the date

Table1

```
Code Period  Datefrom   dateto     Value
001  07/2011 01/07/2009 10/07/2009 100
211  07/2009 01/07/2009 05/07/2009 200
```

From the above table i want to check the date between datefrom and dateto, if the date is in between or equal to datefrom dateto means, it should return the value of the empcode

Tried Query

```
SELECT Value
FROM table1
Where Period = '07/2009'
and Code = '211'
and Cast('02/07/2009' as Datetime) between datefrom and dateto
```

Expected Output:

```
code value
211  200
```

The above query is showing null value, it should return 200.

What wrong in my query?

Comment: Are your columns datetime or varchar? You could try to use 'YYYYMMDD' in the where  clause to be sure that SQL Server does not get mixed up on what is a month and what is a day.

Comment: can you please post the schema of the table so that we could know the data type? i assumed that code and value are varchar right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Cast('02/07/2009' as Datetime)` brings to you 7th February by default
use this instead

```
SELECT Code, Value 
FROM table1 
Where 
    Period = '07/2009' 
and Code = '211'  
and CONVERT(DATETIME, '02/07/2009', 103) between datefrom and dateto
```

**BUT**

You, probably have to convert `datefrom` and `dateto` columns too **if they are of varchar type.**

Comment: I think it's the 7th of february :-) And you don't need to convert those columns IF they have datetime values (instead of string)

Comment: @HansKesting yes, missed about date, but already wrote about columns 8-)

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT Code, Value
 from table1 
 where Period = '07/2009' 
 and Code = '211'
 and DateFrom <='02/07/2009'
 and DateTo >= '02/07/2009'
```

Comment: Wrong! Need to convert string dates from British format. The query is just the same, except Code column in select list

Answer (score -1):

You can use the below query

```
SELECT   code
       , value 
FROM   table1 
WHERE  period = '07/2009' 
AND    code   = '211' 
AND    convert(datetime,'02/07/2009',101) 
       between 
       convert(datetime,datefrom,101) and convert(datetime,dateto,101)
```